# Redirect within wordpress template/plugin

Tags: htaccess, wp-redirect

I've done a bit of googling, searching on forums, etc, and can't find a good answer. 
Here is what I'm doing:
I need to pass a variable in the url to the page and have a rewrite to make it pretty. So, `"mysite.com/ninny/hello-world"` is really `"mysite.com/ninny.php?c=hello-world"`. This is currently in action on a non-wordpress site using `.htaccess` rewrites and php.

I'm trying to create a plugin to do this. Have a file with all the code that is in the `"ninny.php"` file in the plugin and have it appear on the front-end, like a page, with `get_header(),`  and other functions working, to visitors when they visit `mysite.com/ninny` or `"mysite.com/ninny/hello-world"`. A plugin is ideal, although a page template could suffice.

The issue I'm having is that if you rewrite the url for a page that is in the plugin it doesn't load all the Wordpress functions - so you wind up with all kind of fun errors. 
I don't want to call wp-load within the site like that.

What can I do so that the plugin is creating a "page" (not a real entry-in-the-database page), that doesn't go around wordpress like mine currently does.

Is there any way to do a rewrite and have it loading the wordpress functions? Where should I be looking here?

Thank you in advance for anything that points me in the right direction. If this all doesn't make any sense, feel free to ask questions.

Comment: I didn't explain it very well, so here's some further clarification:

I need to be able have a page, it doesn't have to even appear as a page in the admin (although it is fine if it does). The content of this page will be modified based on a variable set in the URL, "?c=".

The reason for a rewrite is that I don't want the url to show it as a variable, but rather as a "pretty" link. So if "c" equals "ninnny" then it would NOT be mysite.com/whateverpageCisappendedto?c=ninny , but rather, mysite.com/whateverpageCisappendedto/ninny/

Answer (score 2):

I think you should take a step back and clarify what you are actually trying to do. Usually with WordPress there is no need to throw around with crazy redirects, virtual pages and file includes. **Although** you *can* do all these things (mentioning [WP_Rewrite](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite)).

When all you want is passing parameters to a page all you have to do is add them to the normal permalink of your page: `mysite.com/ninny/hello-world?c=hello-world`

Comment: +1 and don't forget abour [`add_query_arg()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_query_arg).

Comment: cool, didn't know about this one, thanks!

Comment: I just added a comment above to further explain my post. A much more simple explanation, I think. Let me know if you need further clarification! I think I may have been barking up the wrong tree as far as methods are concerned.